# How to add new property in an object nested in 2 arrays (JSONB postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am looking to you for help in adding a property to a json object nested in 2 arrays.

Table Example :

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    seq_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    data JSONB NOT NULL,
    evt_type TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

example of my JSONB data column in my table:

```
{
   "Id":"1",
   "Calendar":{
      "Entries":[
         {
            "Id": 1,
            "SubEntries":[
               {
                  "ExtId":{
                     "Id":"10",
                     "System": "SampleSys"
                  },
                  "Country":"FR",
                  "Details":[
                     {
                        "ItemId":"1",
                        "Quantity":10,
                     },
                     {
                        "ItemId":"2",
                        "Quantity":3,
                     }
                  ],
                  "RequestId":"222",
                  "TypeId":1,
               }
            ],
            "OrderResult":null
         }
      ],
      "OtherThingsArray":[
         
      ]
   }
}
```

So I need to add new properties into a `SubEntries` object based on the `Id` value of the `ExtId` object (The where clause)

How can I do that please ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add your JSON expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jsonb_set()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html) for this, which takes jsonpath assignments as a text[] (array of text values) as

```
SELECT jsonb_set(
```

- *input_jsonb*,

the starting jsonb document

- *path_array* **'{i,j,k[, ...]}'::text[]**,

the path array, where the series {i, j, k} progresses at each level with either the (string) key or (integer) index (starting at zero)denoting the new key (or index) to populate

- *new_jsonb_value*,

if adding a key-value pair, you can use something like to_jsonb('new_value_string'::text) here to force things to format correctly

- *create_if_not_exists_boolean*

if adding new keys/indexes, give this as *true* so they'll be appended; otherwise you'll be limited to overwriting existing keys

```
)
```

### Example

**json**

```
{
  "array1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "detail": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_set('{"array1": [{"id": 1, "detail": "test"}]}'::jsonb,
    '{array1,0,update}'::TEXT[],
    to_jsonb('new'::text),
    true
)
```

**Output**

```
{
  "array1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "upd": "new",
      "detail": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note** that you can only add 1 nominal level of depth at a time (i.e. either a new key or a new index entry), but you can circumvent this by providing the full depth in the assignment value, or by using jsonb_set() iteratively:

```
select
    jsonb_set( 
jsonb_set('{"array1": [{"id": 1, "detail": "test"}]}'::jsonb, '{array1,0,upd}'::TEXT[], '[{"new": "val"}]'::jsonb, true), 
    '{array1,0,upd,0,check}'::TEXT[],
    '"test_val"',
    true)
```

would be required to produce

```
{
  "array1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "upd": [
        {
          "new": "val",
          "check": "test_val"
        }
      ],
      "detail": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you need other, more complex logic to evaluate *which* values need to be added to which objects, you can try:

- dynamically creating a set of jsonb_set() statements for execution
- using the outputs from queries of jsonb_each() and jsonb_array_elements() to evaluate the row logic down at the SubEntities level, and then using jsonb_object_agg() and jsonb_agg() as appropriate to build the document back up to the root level from the resultant object-arrays and key-value collections